# Converting raw binary data into an image file?

Tags: python, django, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to read a field from an Active Directory entry which contains raw jpeg binary data. I'd like to read that data and convert it to an image file for use in my django-based application. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to handle this data in a nice way. Any ideas?

**Edit**:

To anyone who might come across this in the future: there's a method in python's OS library:

```
os.tmpfile()
```

it creates a file and destroys it once the file descriptor is closed. Very useful for this situation.

Comment: But ... what is your problem? Could you read it? Did you try to store it and use it as an image?

Comment: I guess my problem is just that I am slightly confused. I'm not opening a file to be read -- I'm accessing a field which essentially returns a string from the binary data. I'm not sure how to handle it

Comment: @Brian Save it in a binary file with jpg extension and try to open it :)

Comment: Haha yes, this is what I'm trying to do, but through django's api. It seems like using this method I'd have to save it to a temp location, open it again (this time as a file), and then save that file via django's imagefield and associated methods. There' got to be a better way.

Comment: For the record, this works (what you mentioned). i'm just not sure it's the "django way"

Comment: @Brian Probably not, as my knowledge of django is only comparable to my general ignorance :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is somebody who was having the same problem -- check out the latest post at the bottom.
http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/4214db6699863ded/5d816b02daca3186

Looks like passing raw data to SimpleUploadedFile is what you are looking for.

request._raw_post_data

> The raw HTTP POST data as a byte
>   string. This is useful for processing
>   data in different formats than of
>   conventional HTML forms: binary
>   images, XML payload etc.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects

I know this isn't part of the question, but this looks pretty awesome! `"HttpRequest.read() file-like interface"`
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.read

Comment: My file isn't uploaded though -- it's not attached to the request, and doesn't have any of the attributes that a normal file would have (like name, for example). I can't really figure out how to handle it just as literally a raw string.

Comment: Arg. do you have any idea what format the string is in? Can you paste that somewhere? I want to play with it!

Comment: Give me a few minutes and I'll extract it from AD :)

Comment: Here you go! http://www.heypasteit.com/download/QMG (notice it's a dictionary btw)

Comment: I was able to successfully write the string (directly from AD, not the string I posted -- who knows if it was corrupted along the way) just by writing binary data and giving it a .jpg extension -- I think I might just have to write my own method for doing this, and then save the path in the imagepath field. I can't think of any other way to do it.

Comment: Ahhh roger that. I tried and failed with the string posted (PIL mode guessing..), writing to disk, etc. StringIO() sounds promising if it worked by writing to the disk! If it's never going to be served w/o processing, in-memory might still be good, but otherwise it seems like writing to disk is suggested all around. Glad you figured it out! Seeya